# Plot coordinates near a given set of coordinates on Google maps

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

This is the scenario...
I have a set of lat/long data stored in a db table[id, lat, long, location]. I'm using geo-location to get a user's current physical location(lat and long). When this user accesses the app, allows his location to be shared, I want to get those coordinates that are around his current coordinates, and plot them on a Google Map.
How can this be done?

Example: I have the coordinates for hotels in a city stored in my DB table. When a user visits this city and accesses my app, I want to get from my DB and plot on map only those coordinates that are around him in a certain radius.

Note: I'm using PHP for server side stuff.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Store locator. Google have an article: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

Comment: Hey this example doesn't do what I want! I'm familiar with using db with google maps. My real need is to plot coordinates around a specific location.

Comment: Yes: that's exactly what a store locator is. You are locating POIs within a radius around a location. A store locator finds POIs within a radius around a location. The details are different (you find the location via browser geolocation and have a fairly small radius) but the principle is exactly the same.

Comment: Aha... lemme go through it again...

Comment: Nope man, I couldn't find how it does what I want to do.

Comment: Andrew is right, the example in the store locator represents what you're trying to accomplish.  If your data is in a DB, then you can use a simple query to compute the distance between the user's coordinates and the coordinates in your database, and then sort by distance or select only those records with a distance < X.  However,  even better would be the use of spatial queries in your DB, if it supports those.  Once you have the subset of coordinates, you would send them back down (presuming you're using AJAX) as JSON, and then use JS with the Maps API do display the data (with markers).

Comment: That's it, how do I calculate that distance? Any specific formula?

Comment: Great, found it finally! Thanks a lot guys! @Andrew Leach, can you please put your solution as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You describe a store locator: finding POIs within a radius around a particular point. A store locator finds POIs within a radius around a location. The details in Google's example are different (you find the centre point via browser geolocation and have a fairly small radius) but the principle is exactly the same.

Google's article: developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3